# Ajax response from a servlet is printing twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am facing problem while appending the content of a **div** using ajax.The response from the servlet is printing twice.

Here is the code for both the pages.

**demo.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function run()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById("output");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    content.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
                }
                xhr.open("POST", "demo", true);
                xhr.send(null);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Content" onclick="run();"/>
    <div id="output">This is Static Text.</span><br>
    </div>
</body>
```

**DemoServlet**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/demo"})
public class Demo extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("This is Dynamic Text<br>");
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The final content of the **output** div is:

This is Static Text.

This is Dynamic Text.

This is Dynamic Text.

I am unable to understand why the Dynamic Text is printing twice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly did you learn how to use `XMLHttpRequest`? I'd suggest to re-read that resource or look for a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `onreadystatechange` is being called multiple times, more than one of which is carrying the response.  See [What do the different readystates in XMLHttpRequest mean, and how can I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632774)  Put a breakpoint in your handler to check.

You probably want to add a check that the response is complete:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        content.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
    }
}
```