# AJAX what is a safe implementation of "The request is in process" state 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I want to display the request response as it is being received as it may take several seconds for it to complete. I read that it is 'unsafe' somewhere to use type 3, is that in the case of certain browsers? thanks.

Comment: Do you know *where* you read that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632774/what-do-the-different-readystates-in-xmlhttprequest-mean-and-how-can-i-use-them, "Some XMLHttpRequest implementations may let you see partially received responses in responseText when readyState==3, but this isn't universally supported and shouldn't be relied upon."

Comment: It doesn't say "unsafe", it says "maybe unsupported". You can try to read the `responseText` from a state 3 request, and if you're lucky you get something to work with. Or you don't.