# Javascript:How to obtain a url for a text entered and submitted in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a text box with submit button . I shall retrieve a number from the text box. I have to take this number and respond with a url in the format of url/number  this way - like this it opens the website.But the code is not working.Please help.

```
<html>

<head>
   <title>Numbers Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>



    function loadDoc() {
        var number=document.getElementById("text").value;
        console.log(number);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 || this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                console.log(this.responseText)
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/number", true);

       xhttp.send();  
    }
</script>
<div id="ajax1"></div>
    <h1>AJAX </h1>
    No.:
    <input type="text" id="text" name="text" >
    <button type="button" id="buttonnumber"  onclick="loadDoc()">Submit</button>

 </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Did you try to concatenate the number variable to the url? `xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/" + number, true);`

Comment: Concatenate it or use template literal syntax `xhttp.open("GET", \`http://numbersapi.com/${number}\`, true);`

Comment: i did that , thanks. But the next issue is i want the second text number output to appear in the nxt line , so i did this - document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML += this.responseText+"<br>"; . Now i am getting the o/p of a number twice. How  get it only once

Comment: `xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/"+number",true);`

Comment: yes .  thanks gary . But after this, i have to append the data of the input numbers . So i changed the code - document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML += this.responseText+"<br>"; . But the output is appearing twice with this -->12 is the number of constellations in the ecliptic (or signs of the zodiac). 12 is the number of constellations in the ecliptic (or signs of the zodiac).  How to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

simply change a single statement

**xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/"+number, true);**

final loadDoc function will

```
function loadDoc() {
        var number=document.getElementById("text").value;
        console.log(number);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 || this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                console.log(this.responseText)
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/" + number, true);

       xhttp.send();  
    }
```

Comment: i did that , thanks. But the next issue is i want the second text number output to appear in the nxt line , so i did this - document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML += this.responseText+"<br>"; . Now i am getting the o/p of the number twice. How get it only once

Comment: Output:
12 is the number of constellations in the ecliptic (or signs of the zodiac). 12 is the number of constellations in the ecliptic (or signs of the zodiac).

13 is the number of Oscar nominations of actress Meryl Streep, who holds the record for the most Oscar nominated actress. 13 is the number of Oscar nominations of actress Meryl Streep, who holds the record for the most Oscar nominated actress.

Answer (score 0):

issue is in the line:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/number", true);
```

`number` is variable so you have to append that to url so jsut change it to

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/"+number, true);
```

Comment: i did that , thanks. But the next issue is i want the second text number output to appear in the nxt line , so i did this - document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML += this.responseText+"<br>"; . Now i am getting the o/p of a number twice. How get it only once

Comment: where ? in ajax1 div..? or in consloe?

Comment: Output:
12 is the number of constellations in the ecliptic (or signs of the zodiac). 12 is the number of constellations in the ecliptic (or signs of the zodiac).

13 is the number of Oscar nominations of actress Meryl Streep, who holds the record for the most Oscar nominated actress. 13 is the number of Oscar nominations of actress Meryl Streep, who holds the record for the most Oscar nominated actress.

Comment: in <div id="ajax1"> tag

Comment: `if (this.readyState == 4 || this.status == 200) {
if(document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML == "")
{
                document.getElementById("ajax1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
                console.log(this.responseText)
            }`

Comment: just check for empty before `innertHTML`

Comment: Now nothing appears

Comment: can you check `console.log(this.readyState)` below the `innerHTML`.. bcos i thing it is going twice in that condition.

Comment: No its not  The readystate is going twice. These are the output -2
 3
 4

Comment: what to do. how to avoid the repetition of values.12 is the number of months in a year.
12 is the number of months in a year.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632774/what-do-the-different-readystates-in-xmlhttprequest-mean-and-how-can-i-use-them)

Comment: @MJ.. its even working when i do this -( this.status == 200 & this.readyState==4)